# Reducing the Node height of a TreeView

Tags: delphi, winapi, treeview

Inside the Window 10 File Explorer tree (left pane), there are vertical spaces between the `Quick access`, `OneDrive` and `This PC`:

[image: Unused nodes in the Windows File Explorer]

How can I use spaces like this in a WinAPI [TreeView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759988(v=vs.85).aspx)?

I can place "empty" nodes there. They will have the same height, like other "real" nodes too. But I want to have spaces with the half height of a normal node, like used in the Windows Explorer.

Using `TreeView_SetItem` allows me to enlarge height of a `Node` - but I want to reduce it to the half.

Comment: FWIW, that control isn't a Windows tree view. It's a `DirectUIHWND` control. You cannot use that control. I'm not sure if the Windows tree view control offers you any spacing options. I would not be at all surprised if it did not.

Comment: It is a TreeView though, don't let wrapper class name to deceive you. I think you can try to make it look like by setting TVITEMEX.iIntegral member with appropriate mask.

Comment: From shell point of view this maps to NSTCS2_DISPLAYPADDING style I think.

Comment: @bunglehead: `TVITEMEX.iIntegral` is a multiplyer of the standard item height - but I want to _reduce_ the height. `INameSpaceTreeControl2::SetControlStyle2` can set a padding for all items - but I want to reduce the height of one item.

Comment: @Tahtu: Padding is applied to all root nodes, not for every node. You're asking two contradictory questions - "How can I use spaces like this" - this is how. Do you have an example application or any place in windows shell that reduces item height for a single item? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @bunglehead No, it's not a Win32 tree view control, SysTreeView32. It's DirectUIHWND.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it is SysTreeView32, DirectUIHWND is container window several levels above. Of course it's not SysTreeView32 used directly, but through NamespaceTreeControl. You can verify all of that using any window enumeration program, I just tested on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: @bunglehead Hmm, that's very interesting. I did not know that. Thank you.